# How do I move expedition-specific items between save slots?

Tags: no-mans-sky

Recently I was looking into all the old expedition-specific save files for No Man Sky, looking for a decent way to clean up the mess without loosing the weird items each expedition came with.

By completing an expedition the player gets some rewards that can be claimed at the Anomaly on each separate save slot. But those aren't the only "expedition exclusive" items.

Consider from example the Emergence Expedition: completion rewards include a cosmetic helmet, a worm egg, banners and so on. But there is no way to obtain the lore-related quest items from said Expedition on another save since those were exclusive to the expedition.

[image]

The Writhing Manuscript in the picture above is an example of such items: it has no real use outside the expedition but it would still be nice to be able to keep it as a memento without having to deal with an increasing number of useless save slots (since each expedition is played on a separate slot).

Obviously, if you have some trustworthy friend that plays the game the solution is simple: go online on the to-be-deleted expedition save, transfer all the memento items to them, log on the main save, get your items back.

... but what can you do if you are alone? Is there any exploit that you can use? Could for example a base be used as a storage, published online and the item be retrieved on a different slot?