# Any way to avoid having unwanted bases shared to your main save in the No Man's Sky Omega update?

Tags: no-mans-sky

The Omega update for No Man's Sky introduced a new way to start expeditions from your main save slot.

> - Players can choose to begin an expedition from a new terminal aboard the Space Anomaly.
> - Before starting the expedition, players are able to load this terminal with a choice of items and packaged equipment.
> - The expedition will then begin as normal. Upon reaching the Space Anomaly, players will be able to retrieve these stored items to aid them with their progress.
> - With an expedition in progress, players can use this terminal (or an option within the main menu) to freely switch between continuing the expedition or pausing it.
> - Pausing the expedition allows players to switch back to their “primary” save for that slot and dip in and out of the expedition as they wish.

[image]

At the end of the expedition...

> - Players will be able to return technology and items to their primary save via the same terminal used to start the expedition. Alternatively, unwanted items will be sold automatically and converted to units or nanites as appropriate.
> - All earned units, nanites and quicksilver will be automatically returned to your primary save on completion of the expedition.
> - ***All discoveries will be automatically shared with the primary save. Bases will be shared to the primary save on completion of the expedition.***
> - At the end of the expedition, additional unit or nanite rewards will be awarded based on other measures of progress, such as Sentinels killed, words learned or base parts constructed.

[image]

On paper this seems like a decent way to finally [move Expedition memento items between saves](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/401871/no-mans-sky-moving-expedition-specific-items-between-save-slots). But it appears this feature has been over-complicated and comes with two big issues:

- first, it only works for new Expeditions started from a main save: the system can only transfer items back to the primary save used to start the expedition. So, until we get a re-run, old expedition items are still locked to their slot since they aren't associated to any primary slot.
- second and more important, this seems to brute-force you into sharing bases and discoveries from the expedition to the main save.

The second feature looks like it is just asking for issue.

- often expeditions force you to build bases just to complete a milestone. As a result, those are zero effort "four walls and a floor" bases that you don't care about. Now... you get those copied to you main save and you will have to manually clean them up (note: assuming your main save gains ownership of those).
- even worse, you get discovery copied to your main save. And I assume that include other players ones. Since expedition love to force you to online to be able to do some step (like community milestones) this often means getting idiot players harassing content in your Expedition slot like bad, out of context or plain swear words names for planets/fauna/flora, bases placed to hinder progression (like people using glitches to place bases over the expedition meeting points) etc. All this feature does is making all this trash happily carry over to your main save too (if I REALLY wanted to visit an expedition planet on my main save... portal coordinates exist for a reason).

Am I missing something in all of this? This feature is looking like it really wants to fill your game with "Peppa Pig" creatures, "Bikini Bottoms" planets and so on (just to avoid mentioning those who think they are really adult with their nsfw names, nazi cross shaped bases and so on).

**Can I use this feature and still keep my main save clean from other players created content? Notice that I suspect you are also forced to go online on the main save to access the expedition starting menu.**